# vb.net wildcard file search exception

Tags: vb.net, file, wildcard, messagebox

im totally new to vb.net

I figured how to find files using wildcard and it works fine but i need error meassage if file not found.
here's my code.
any help highly appreciated !

```
    For Each hist In Directory.GetFiles("C:\temp", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        If File.Exists(hist) Then
            File.Copy(hist, Path.Combine("C:\temp\1", Path.GetFileName(hist)), True)
            MessageBox.Show("file exist and copied") <-- this message shows up and files are copied

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("No files. Folder is empty !") <--this message never shows up when folder is empty . no files at all


        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Why would it ever show up? Why are you expecting a file that you just found to not be found? Are you actually wanting to show that message if there are no files at all?  If so, assign the result of `GetFiles` to a variable and then test the `Length` of the array or call `Any`.  That will tell you if there are files or not and, if not, you can display your message.  If there are files, then you loop through them.

Comment: Yes. I.m expecting 2nd message only if there are no files atl. empty folder.

Comment: @czechu82 If there are no files in the target folder, the foreach loop won't execute any iterations.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely you would see that second message. You are grabbing the list of files from the OS directly - so, at least at the time that you retrieve the file name that file exists. If you wanted to simulate a case where the file doesn't exist, place a break point on the **IF File.Exists(hist) Then** line. While the program is paused there, go find and delete whatever the current file is. Then continue the program.

Answer (score 0):

i got it working.
here's what i added before foreach :

```
Dim myDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("c:\temp\")
        If (myDir.EnumerateFiles().Any()) Then


 foreach ....


else

MessageBox.Show("no files in directory ")   <-- my message
```

thanks for advice!!